# Best way to use list comprehension on a complex statement

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a python line `fabric.connection.Connection("192.168.3.100", port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs = {"password" : "Raspberry"})` that I want to put into a list, ideally using list comprehension to increment the last number of the IP address for each element in the list.

For instance I want the list to look like this (but with many more elements in it of course):

`LIST_A = [("192.168.3.100", port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs = {"password" : "Raspberry"}), ("192.168.3.101", port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs = {"password" : "Raspberry"}), ("192.168.3.102", port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs = {"password" : "Raspberry"})]`

Notice how the IP increases for each item in the list.

Is there any way to do this with list comprehension or do I need to copy/paste it over and over again?

I'm thinking something along the lines of

`LIST_A = [fabric.connection.Connection("192.168.3.{}", port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs = {"password" : "Raspberry"}).format(x + 1) for x in range(40)]`

But that doesn't work because there are all kinds of data types in that statement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zfill` and `str.format`:

```
r = ["192.168.3.1{}".format(str(i).zfill(2)) for i in range(3)]
new_r = [fabric.connection.Connection(i, port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs = {"password" : "Raspberry"}) for i in r]
print(r)
```

Output:

```
['192.168.3.100', '192.168.3.101', '192.168.3.102']
```

Comment: Is there any way to use this to have the output the full line instead of just the IP alone. I need to be able to iterate through to run the commands. I.e.: `List[idx] = fabric.connection.Connection("192.168.3.100", port=22, user="pi", connect_kwargs = {"password" : "Raspberry"})`

Comment: Sorry I thought the output was for `new_r` instead of `r`. This is exactly what I need. TY

Comment: @Matt No problem. `r` is not entirely necessary, as the operation in the comprehension can be placed in `new_r`, although the above is much more readable.

Comment: @Matt `rsplit` is not called on any objects in the comprehension of `new_r`. Most likely that is an error raised from `fabric.connection.Connection`. Can you post the code currently giving the error, or provide a link to the documentation for `fabric.connection.Connection`.

Comment: Nevermind I totally botched copying over the code. I used the varaible `r` instead of `i` in the second line